# Prune Lower Ticks from Log Axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to prune the lowest most tick on a matplotlib log-axis? Currently, pruning turns off all major tick marks.

```python
from matplotlib import ticker

x = np.logspace(0, 3, 101)
y = np.log10(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set_xscale("log")

nbins = len(ax.get_xticklabels())
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MaxNLocator(nbins=nbins, prune="lower"))
```

[image: Output of above]

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this question. `prune = "lower"` would turn off the leftmost tick. But you are talking about several ticks? Also you say it is turning off all major tickmarks, but there is one major tickmark shown in the plot. Maybe instead of describing the command that fails, can you also describe how you would like the plot to look like instead?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I am saying that setting `prune="lower"` is supposed to turn off the lowest/left most tick. Instead, it is turning off all major ticks.